# How to display x raise to y in UIlabel

Tags: iphone, ios4, nsstring, uilabel

how can I display 5 raise to 1/3 in iphone i.e I want 1/3 written above 5 can anyone help please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Found this solution, hope so it would be helpful for you.

x to the power of y in a UILabel could be easy. Just replace your indices with unicode superscript characters... I use the following method to turn an integer into a string with superscript characters.

```
+(NSString *)convertIntToSuperscript:(int)i 
{
    NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"⁰", @"¹", @"²", @"³", @"⁴", @"⁵", @"⁶", @"⁷", @"⁸", @"⁹", nil];
    if (i >= 0 && i <= 9) {
        NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [array objectAtIndex:i]];
        [array release];
        return myString;
    }
    else {
        NSString *base = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i];
        NSMutableString *newString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        for (int b = 0; b<[base length]; b++) {
            int temp = [[base substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(b, 1)] intValue];
            [newString appendString:[array objectAtIndex:temp]];
        }
        [array release];
        NSString *returnString = [NSString stringWithString:newString];
        [newString release];
        return returnString;
    }    
}
```

Comment: how did you write @"⁰" i.e 0 in superscript

Comment: it did but for how to write in superscript, are there any combinations of keys or some other change, I want to change as for e.g. I want to show 1/3 in superscript. Thank You

Comment: you need to enable the character viewer... go to System Preferences > Language & Text > Input Sources, and tick the Keyboard & Character Viewer

Comment: Then it should appear in the menu bar, a little icon which looks like a window with an asterix in it - click it, then click show character viewer, then click digits, and you will see the superscript chars.

Answer (score 2):

Try this NSString *cmsquare=@"cm\u00B2";
It will display cm².

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that but you need custom UILabel, either Make it by yourself or Get it Open Source..